# How does one obtain the pid of a process started from powershell?

Tags: powershell, pid

If I use powershell to run an external command, how do I obtain it's pid?

I'd like to obtain it for purposes of gracefully exiting it later (not just straight up killing the process, but rather doing it in more the sense of a `finally` block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using System.Diagnostics.Process object, you can start a process, and return a Process object, which includes the newly created process PID.

For example:

```
$Process = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start("nssm.exe")   
Write-Host $Process.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

## [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6)

```
Write-Output (Get-Process -Name "Sonos").Id
```

That will get you the PID - however based on what you're describing it's easier to the output of `Get-Process` to a variable and deal with the object instead

```
try {
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sonos\Sonos.exe"
    Write-Output $process.Id
}
catch {
    throw
}
finally {
    if ($process) {
        Stop-Process -InputObject $process
        # Alternative: $process | Stop-Process
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to start a process from a script and then kill the process with the same script

Comment: @leeand00 - added a `Start-Process` for you.